# Store a whole XML as metadata inside a PDF file?

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, xmp

I'm trying to read a pdf file, to extract some info from it, and it seems like a way to do it is to set some metadata, and then retrieve it using something like the as3-xmp lib.

However, what I'm trying to write inside as metadata is a whole xml, and it is probably big, something like hundreds of lines.

Is this possible using XMP?.

Comment: "Hundreds of lines" should not be a problem. The metadata of a single included image already may cross that line. I'd say, go for it. ("Hundreds of lines" of XML doesn't really translate in a lot of data. Besides, it's usually plain ASCII text and so very well compressible.)

Comment: Thanks for your input!, a doubt though, in Adobe Acrobat for example you have only the option to add a list of key-value like entries, is there a way to append an xml?, or should I manually edit the metadata somewhere?.

Comment: We do this with PDF Fields, the limit is is 65kb and if needed, we split the XML into multiple fields and recontruct it server side.

Comment: Note, you could also just use a file attachment unless you wish to somewhat "hide" the XML from someone who has the PDF.

Comment: I googled PDF Fields, but nothing shows up that seems to resemble what you are using. Also, is there a way to access these fields by code? (AS3).